# Finish registration notice doesn't look designed right

Tags: bug, design, unregistered-users, sign-up

Being an unregistered user, you can proceed with finishing the registration. In this case, you will see the same page as in a normal registration, but with a misaligned notice above:

> [image]

Notice states:

> Finish signing up by using any of the following options:

This notice looks like a raw text that doesn't fit into site's design somehow. Could this please be fixed?